# Prolog can't figure out how to append

Tags: prolog

I have a simple problem, and I know why what I'm doing is wrong, I just dont know how to do what I want.
I want to be able to find the max of list X and then append it to the result Xs. It would recurse slowly sorting the list until it was finished. I know there are better sorting algorithms but I want to try and make my problem work.

These are the 2 version of the code that I have tried but I seem to be getting no where

```
mysort([],_).
mysort([X,Y], Xs) :- max(X,M), mysort(Y,[M|Xs]).
```

```
mysort([],_).
mysort([X,Y], Xs) :- max(X,M),append(Xs, [M], Xs) mysort(Y,[M|Xs]).
```

I would hope to have some kind of hint to completing this code, or someone fixing this silly problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, but maybe you can use some of this:

Example one:

```
mysort(List, Result) :-
   aggregate(max(X), member(X, List), Result).
```

Result:

```
mysort([1,2,3,4], Result).
Result = 4
```

Example two:

```
mysort(List, MaxList, Result) :-
    aggregate(max(X), member(X, List), Max),
    append(MaxList, [Max], Result).
```

Result:

```
mysort([1,2,300,3], [100, 200], Result)
Result = [100, 200, 300]
```

Example three:

```
mysort(List, Result) :- mysort(List, [], Result).
mysort([], Result, Result).
mysort([H | T], Tmp, Result) :-
    aggregate(max(X), member(X, H), Max), 
    TmpResult = [Max | Tmp], 
    mysort(T, TmpResult, Result).
```

Result:

```
mysort([[122,2,3,4, 6, 10], [127,2,3,4, 6, 10], [127,2,3,4, 6, 10]], Result).
Result = [127, 127, 122]
```

Answer (score 0):

`[X,Y]` is a list of 2 elements, then is not what you want.
Instead, you should concentrate on building a predicate select_max/3, that 'extracts' the maximal value and returns it **and** the list without it.
We could code it adapting the select/3 library predicate:

```
select_max(Max,List,Rest) :-
  select(Max,List,Rest),
  \+ (member(Other,List),Other@>Max).
```

Now you can try to build the main recursive mysort/2, I will left to you as an exercise (remember that the base case should instantiate the output list to empty).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a predicate to **select a maximum element**, separating it from the rest of the list. To do so:

- Start by taking the first element of the list `[X|Xs]` as the current maximum element.
- Then, recursively traverse the rest of the list (`Xs`) by comparing the current maximum element (`X0`) to the current first element (`X1`), separating the biggest of the two and putting the other in the rest.
- Finally, when the list is empty, the current maximum element (`Max`) is indeed the maximum element of the original list.

```
% select_max(-Max, +List, -Rest)

  select_max(Max, [X|Xs], Rest) :-
      select_max(Xs, X, Max, Rest).

  select_max([], Max, Max, []).
  select_max([X1|Xs], X0, Max, [Lesser|Rest]) :-
      compare(Relation, X0, X1),
      sorted(Relation, X0, X1, Lesser, Bigger),
      select_max(Xs, Bigger, Max, Rest).

  sorted(=, A, B, A, B).
  sorted(<, A, B, A, B).
  sorted(>, A, B, B, A).
```

Example:

```
?- trace(select_max, +all), select_max(M, [5,3,7,1], R), trace(select_max, -all).
%         select_max/3: [all]
%         select_max/4: [all]
 T [11] Call: select_max(_30924434, [5, 3, 7, 1], _30924438)
 T [20] Call: select_max([3, 7, 1], 5, _30924434, _30924438)
 T [29] Call: select_max([7, 1], 5, _30924434, _30929268)
 T [38] Call: select_max([1], 7, _30924434, _30930168)
 T [47] Call: select_max([], 7, _30924434, _30931068)
 T [47] Exit: select_max([], 7, 7, [])
 T [38] Exit: select_max([1], 7, 7, [1])
 T [29] Exit: select_max([7, 1], 5, 7, [5, 1])
 T [20] Exit: select_max([3, 7, 1], 5, 7, [3, 5, 1])
 T [11] Exit: select_max(7, [5, 3, 7, 1], [3, 5, 1])
%         select_max/3: Not tracing
%         select_max/4: Not tracing
M = 7,
R = [3, 5, 1].
```

Afterwards, you should use predicate `select_max/3` to define your sorting algorithm (aka. **Bubble Sort**) as follows:

```
% mysort(+List, -SortedList)

  mysort(List, SortedList) :-
      mysort(List, [], SortedList).

  mysort([], SortedList, SortedList).
  mysort([X|Xs], SortedSuffix, SortedList) :-
      select_max(Max, [X|Xs], Rest),
      mysort(Rest, [Max|SortedSuffix], SortedList).
```

Example:

```
?- trace(mysort, +all), mysort([5,3,7,1], S), trace(mysort, -all).
%         mysort/2: [all]
%         mysort/3: [all]
 T [11] Call: mysort([5, 3, 7, 1], _36832)
 T [20] Call: mysort([5, 3, 7, 1], [], _36832)
 T [29] Call: mysort([3, 5, 1], [7], _36832)
 T [38] Call: mysort([3, 1], [5, 7], _36832)
 T [47] Call: mysort([1], [3, 5, 7], _36832)
 T [56] Call: mysort([], [1, 3, 5, 7], _36832)
 T [56] Exit: mysort([], [1, 3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7])
 T [47] Exit: mysort([1], [3, 5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7])
 T [38] Exit: mysort([3, 1], [5, 7], [1, 3, 5, 7])
 T [29] Exit: mysort([3, 5, 1], [7], [1, 3, 5, 7])
 T [20] Exit: mysort([5, 3, 7, 1], [], [1, 3, 5, 7])
 T [11] Exit: mysort([5, 3, 7, 1], [1, 3, 5, 7])
%         mysort/2: Not tracing
%         mysort/3: Not tracing
S = [1, 3, 5, 7].
```

More examples:

```
?- mysort([], S).
S = [].

?- mysort([5], S).
S = [5].

?- randseq(5, 100, L), mysort(L, S).
L = [77, 68, 11, 38, 65],
S = [11, 38, 65, 68, 77].

?- randseq(7, 100, L), mysort(L, S).
L = [57, 5, 16, 8, 11, 53, 55],
S = [5, 8, 11, 16, 53, 55, 57].
```